# When I change slug, will WordPress create redirect from the old URL?

Tags: redirect, slug

When I change a slug from `post-a` to `post-b`, will WordPress create a redirect from `/post-a` to `/post-b`, like HTTP 301 or something similar? If not, is there a plugin for that?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I just went and tested this (WP 3.3.1), the wordpress core will automatically do a redirect if you change the post slug, even if you change the slug from `post-a` to `post-b` and then to `post-c`, `post-a` will return a 301 to `post-c`. That said, the redirection plugin that Mike Jolley recommended is an outstanding plugin and a great way to monitor for 404 errors and such.

Comment: Just to add a note, this built-in redirection doesn't work when the part of URL that is not the slug changes, e.g. when the pattern is `/[year]/[month]/[date]/[slug]` and the date changes, WordPress will not create a redirect. A plugin is necessary in that case.

Comment: Where abouts in the DB is this redirect rule saved? Cheers

Comment: @raison it's in `wp_postmeta` table and `meta_key` is `_wp_old_slug`. with this query you can see all of them `SELECT * FROM \`wp_postmeta\` where meta_key = "_wp_old_slug"`.

Answer (score 5):

This plugin can be used to monitor URL changes like that and set up redirection automatically:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/redirection/

Comment: If only it worked :( I ended up using http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/quick-pagepost-redirect-plugin/ though it lacks some features.

Comment: Yes, it did work perfectly until at least the middle of 2012 on one of my fairly complex WP installs (always autoupdated as new stable releases are pushed by WP). However something's broken in its autosensing routine for when slugs are modified, I only just noticed today on a 3.5.1 install so can't be sure when this it first stopped automatically adding rules for modified slugs. That's a shame. :( Guess we should all donate to the dev to encourage him to fix the bug!